# Python function returns None for non emptylist

Tags: python, function

I have written a recursive function to make queries to Racktables database and follow the connections between objects and put them in a list.

All the results get appended and extended to a list that I give as argument.
The function works up to the `return` statement, but the list gives `None` after being returned

I have added some `print` statements in the function to debug, and the list contains the data I need up to that point:

```
def plink(Objid, PortId, mylist):

    if len(mylist) < 2:                         #If this is the first run put he initial data in the list
        mylist.append(Objid)
        mylist.append(PortId)

    res = rt.GetLink(PortId)                    #check if port is connected 

    if res == (False, False):
        print 'exiting because not connected'   #debug
        return mylist                           #If not connected return list

    nextObj = rt.GetPortObjid(res[1])
    mylist.extend(res)
    mylist.append(nextObj)

    ispatch = rt.CheckObjType(nextObj, 50080)
    if ispatch[0][0] == 0:                      #If connected to a non-patch-unit, add data to list and exit
        print "exiting because next object {0} is not a patchunit, mylist is {1}".format(nextObj, mylist)  #debug
        return mylist

    patchPorts = rt.GetAllPorts(nextObj)

    if len(patchPorts) != 2:                    #check if the patchunit has the right number of ports
        mylist.append("Error, patch-unit must have exactly two ports")
        return mylist

    if patchPorts[0][2] == res[1]:              #check which port is unseen and call the function again
        print mylist
        plink(nextObj, patchPorts[1][2], mylist)
    else:
        print mylist
        plink(nextObj, patchPorts[0][2], mylist)

results = ['Initial data']
allconn = plink(159, 947, results)
print "The full connection is {0}".format(allconn)
```

(I have skipped the DB constructs here)

Running this code gives:

```
['Initial data', 159, 947, 'C150303-056', 4882, 1591L]
['Initial data', 159, 947, 'C150303-056', 4882, 1591L, 'C140917-056', 4689, 727L]
exiting because next object 1114 is not a patchunit, mylist is ['Initial data', 159, 947, 'C150303-056', 4882, 1591L, 'C140917-056', 4689, 727L, 'C140908-001', 3842, 1114L]
The full connection is None
```

The debug prints show the list being populated exactly as I it is supposed to, but then I get None when printing outside the function, also after assigning to variable beforehand.

I am writing this to run it on a CentOS 6 server with python 2.6. I could run it in virtualenv, as a last resort, but I would avoid it if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if patchPorts[0][2] == res[1]:              #check which port is unseen and call the function again
    print mylist
    plink(nextObj, patchPorts[1][2], mylist)
else:
    print mylist
    plink(nextObj, patchPorts[0][2], mylist)
```

Calling a function recursively does not automatically make the inner call pass the return value up to the outer call. You still need to explicitly `return`.

```
if patchPorts[0][2] == res[1]:              #check which port is unseen and call the function again
    print mylist
    return plink(nextObj, patchPorts[1][2], mylist)
else:
    print mylist
    return plink(nextObj, patchPorts[0][2], mylist)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot, it would have taken me ages to find this info in the docs. I will accept the answer as soon as I am allowed to

Comment: Solving 'None is returned' in Python 101: (1) Is it recursive? _yes_ → (2) Where is the missing return statement? _solved_

Comment: So, the data was kept in mylist inside the function between recursions, but not passed to the last inner instance of mylist? This is very difficult to debug ...

Comment: @Bruno9779, may I self-reference my comment above? :)

Comment: @N. Wouda I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @Bruno9779 Just think about what the first call to plink will do, (without worrying about what subsequent calls are doing). If you follow the logic, you will realize that it won't return mylist unless res == (False, False). When a python function doesn't return anything, it  returns None by default. Keep in mind that you actually don't even need the return value anyway since you are modifying the parameter you passed in. You would get the correct result if your last statement was this: `print "The full connection is {0}".format(results)`

Comment: All this comments are a wealth of knowledge, thanks. @Aaron Taggart, I didn't know that, coming from perl I haven grasped the handling of variables scope yet