# Class BST, find value

Tags: python, algorithm

I am having problems with a BST; I wrote a class that represents BSTs but I can't return `True` or `False` whether a number is in the BST or not. Any idea why it always returns `None`? It only gives me the right answer when I ask about the root.

```
class DrzewoBST:
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        self.val = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "[%s, %s, %s]" % (self.left, str(self.val), self.right)

    def wstawianie(self, wartosc):
        if self is None:
            self = DrzewoBST(wartosc)
        if wartosc < self.val:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = DrzewoBST(wartosc)
            else:
                self.left.wstawianie(wartosc)
        elif wartosc > self.val:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = DrzewoBST(wartosc)
            else:
                self.right.wstawianie(wartosc)

    def wyszukiwanie(self, liczba):
        print(self.val)
        if self is None:
            return False
        if int(self.val) == liczba:
            return True
        if liczba < self.val:
            self.left.wyszukiwanie(liczba)
        else:
            self.right.wyszukiwanie(liczba)

     t = DrzewoBST(2)
     t.wstawianie(3)
     t.wstawianie(3)
     print(t.wyszukiwanie(3))
```

That works only when I try `t.wyszukiwanie(2)` (that gives me `True`) but when I try `t.wyszukiwanie(3)` I got `False`; I should get `True` because 3 is in the BST.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function returns None for non emptylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315989/python-function-returns-none-for-non-emptylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `wyszukiwanie` doesn't return anything. Add `return` statement.

```
if liczba < self.val:
    return self.left.wyszukiwanie(liczba)
else:
    return self.right.wyszukiwanie(liczba)
```